# GWT: add CellList members to Flow Panel one by one

Tags: list, gwt, cell, flowpanel

Is there a way to add CellList members to Flow panel one by one instead of adding CellList itself to the panel?

for example.

```
private static final CellList<MyNodeInfo> myNodeCellList = 
     new CellList<MyNodeInfo>(MyNodeInfoCell.getInstance());
static List<MyNodeInfo> myNodeList = new ArrayList<MyNodeInfo>();
private static final FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();

...
myNodeCellList.setRowData(myNodeList);
...
// <<<<<<<<<
flowPanel.add(myNodeCellList); 
// >>>>>>>>>
for (int i=0; i< myNodeCellList.size(); i++) {

  // want to add indivisual member of myNodeCellList
  flowPanel.add(...);
}
// **<- want to change like this!!**
```

An add() method of FlowPanel get Widget as an input parameter.

An CellList memeber can be an Element(with getElement()), but can't be a Widget.

Can each CellList member be a widget?

Comment: myNodeCell has three text field and one image.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the `SelectionModel` and things like that (keyboard navigation, etc.) then you can create one `CellWidget` per `MyNodeInfo` in your list.

But `CellList` (and other `AbstractHasData` widgets) is not designed for what you're looking after.

Comment: Thanks. I will try! If CellWidget works, it needs not to use CellList. Nonetheless for handling of CellWidget click event I have to do some extra works.

Answer (score 0):

Own answer.

It is enough to add myNodeCellList(whose rowData is myNodeList) to FlowPanel.

I add a container to warp FlowPanel.

Then works.